# I18n.t does not always load in Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

There has been odd behavior of `I18n.t` with our Rails 4.2 app in development. There was no problem with I18n.t until recently. Without changes in app's configuration, the I18n.t does not load in development. Occasionally the page refresh itself and load with translation. However most of time, there is `translation missing` error with every `I18n.t`.

Here is the `local.rb` under initializers:

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
I18n.default_locale = 'zh-CN' if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

There is no problem with I18n.t in production environment. Anyone see this problem before? What's the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to low speed internet.